# What is the difference between mapM_ and mapM in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've already checked Hoogle, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM, which says that `mapM_` ignores the results.

However, I still don't have idea how to use it properly.

```
main = mapM_ (putStrLn.show) [1,2]

main = mapM (putStrLn.show) [1,2]

main = map (putStrLn.show) [1,2]
```

Comment: That is the only difference. `mapM_` returns `m ()` and `mapM` returns `m [b]`, so if you want the results, use `mapM`. If you don't want the results (e.g., you're only interested in the side effects), use `mapM_`.

Comment: Two out of three of those codes *do* work.

Comment: sorry it's kind of my misunderstand, I'm gonna change.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`mapM_` is useful for executing something only for its side effects. For example, printing a string to standard output doesn't return anything useful - it returns `()`. If we have a list of three strings, we would end up accumulating a list`[(), (), ()]`. Building this list has a runtime cost, both in terms of speed and memory usage, so by using `mapM_` we can skip this step entirely.

However, sometimes we need to execute side effects *and* build up a list of the results. If we have a function such as

```
lookupUserById :: UserId -> IO User
```

Then we can use this to inflate a list of `UserId`s to a list of `User`s:

```
lookupUsers :: [UserId] -> IO [User]
lookupUsers = mapM lookupUserById
```

Comment: "Building this list has a runtime cost". In a lazy language, if we never actually consume anything from the list, does that cost still apply?

Answer (score 20):

The core idea is that `mapM` maps an "action" (ie function of type `a -> m b`) over a list and gives you all the results as a `m [b]`. `mapM_` does the same thing, but never collects the results, returning a `m ()`.

If you care about the results of your `a -> m b` function (ie the `b`s), use `mapM`. If you only care about the effect, whatever it is, but not the resulting value, use `mapM_` because it can be more efficient and, more importantly, *makes your intentions clear*.

You would always use `mapM_` with functions of the type `a -> m ()`, like `print` or `putStrLn`. These functions return `()` to signify that only the effect matters. If you used `mapM`, you'd get a list of `()` (ie `[(), (), ()]`), which would be completely useless but waste some memory. If you use `mapM_`, you would just get a `()`, but it would still print everything.

On the other hand, if you do care about the returned values, use `mapM`. As a hypothetical example, imagine a function `fetchUrl :: Url -> IO Response`—chances are, you care about the response you get for each URL. So for this, you'd use `mapM` to get a lists of responses out that you can then use in the rest of your code.

So: `mapM` if you care about the results and `mapM_` if you don't.

Normal `map` is something different: it takes a normal function (`a -> b`) instead of one using a monad (`a -> m b`). This means that it *cannot* have any sort of effect besides returning the changed list. You would use it if you want to transform a list using a normal function. `map_` doesn't exist because, since you don't have any effects, you *always* care about the results of using `map`.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you use the rather specific "action" in your answer? Wouldn't Maybe (Option in F#) be a potential `m` in `a -> m b` ? It'd be great if you could clarify that a bit for newbies such as myself :)

Answer (score 9):

In more general terms, the difference is that `mapM_` only needs to ["consume"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) all elements of the input, whereas `mapM` also needs to "re-build" the data structure, with new values. That's pretty much trivial for lists: you only need to [traverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html) along the cons-cells, updating values with those received from the action you map. But it doesn't work that easily for containers whose structure depends on the actual contained values. So e.g. for `Data.Set` you can't define the equivalent of `mapM` with type `(a -> m b) -> Set a -> m (Set b)` – it is an instance of [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable), but not of [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable)

Answer (score 4):

mapM_ ignores the result. This means, that no return value will be returned. You can see this in interactive mode:

```
Prelude> mapM (putStrLn . show) [1,2]
1
2
[(),()]
Prelude> mapM_ (putStrLn . show) [1,2]
1
2
```

Comment: Something is always returned unless there's an error or the computation fails to terminate. GHCi just doesn't print out the result of an `IO` action if that result is `()`. If you wrote `mapM_ (putStrLn . show) [1,2] >>= print`, you'd get `1`, `2`, and `()`.