# What is the equivalent of mapM and mapM_ in idris2?

Tags: monads, idris, idris2

I know there is the `mapM` function that applies a monadic action to a list and returns one monadic value containing a list. (See e.g.
[What is the difference between mapM_ and mapM in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609062/4196578))

But I couldn't find any `mapM` (or `mapM_` or the underlying `sequence`) function in idris2 (as of 0.6.0). The only thing I could find is a [foldM](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Monad.html).

*Am I expected to roll out my own version of `mapM` based on `foldM`, or is it provided elsewhere in Idris2?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [you want](https://test.idris-lang.org/Idris2/prelude/docs/Prelude.Interfaces.html#Prelude.Interfaces.traverse)

```
traverse : Traversable t => Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

[and](https://test.idris-lang.org/Idris2/prelude/docs/Prelude.Interfaces.html#Prelude.Interfaces.traverse_)

```
traverse_ : Applicative f => Foldable t => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
```

Note `sequence = traverse id`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I just found by trial that there is actually a `sequence` function (which didn't show up in a Google search):

```
Prelude.sequence : Applicative f => Traversable t => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

It seems to be the same as Haskell's `sequence` function, and `mapM` can be defined the same way as:

```
mapM f = sequence . map f
```